# Como mostrar mi pdf con fpdf sin perder los estilos de mi tabla

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

me gustaria mostrar mis datos en formato PDF mediante FPDF sin perder los estilos que he aplicado. El PDF se muestra pero el problema esta en que despues de eso, tambien muestra este error **Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in**
Durante mi investigacion, me he dado cuenta de que es porque tengo varios **echo** en mi tabla pero hasta ahora no se como conseguir lo que quiero.

Este es mi codigo

**Estos son los estilos que intento aplicar a la pagina o al PDF**

```
<style>
  
  .datos_clientes .prescripcciones {
   border: solid 1px black;
padding: 4px;
  }

   .doctor2{

    text-align: center;
    padding: ;

  }
  .doctor{
    text-align: right;
    padding: 40px;
  }

  .observaciones{

    text-align: center;
  }

 .td_paciente{
  text-align: center;
 }



.textura{
  font-family: 'BrixSansRegular';
  font-size: 11pt;
}
.h2{
  font-family: 'BrixSansBlack';
  font-size: 16pt;
}
.h3{
  font-family: 'BrixSansBlack';
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: block;
  background: #0a4661;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#page_pdf{
  width: 95%;
  margin: 15px auto 10px auto;
}

#factura_head, #factura_cliente, #prescripcion, #factura_detalle{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.logo_factura{
  width: 15%;
  
}
.info_empresa{
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.info_factura{
  /*width: 25%;*/
}
.info_cliente{
  width: 100%;
}
.datos_cliente{
  width: 100%;
}
.datos_cliente tr td{
  width: 50%;
}
.datos_cliente{
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
.datos_cliente label{
  width: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.datos_cliente p{
  display: inline-block;
}

.textright{
  text-align: right;
}
.textleft{
  text-align: left;
}
.textcenter{
  text-align: center;
}
.round{
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #0a4661;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.round p{
  padding: 0 15px;
}

#factura_detalle{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#factura_detalle thead th{
  background: #058167;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
}
#detalle_productos tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ededed;
}
#detalle_totales span{
  font-family: 'BrixSansBlack';
}
.nota{
  font-size: 8pt;
}
.label_gracias{
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.anulada{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
</style>
```

**Codigo PHP y HTML**

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['id_tratamiento']) && (!empty($_GET['id_tratamiento']))  && is_numeric($_GET['id_tratamiento']) == 1){
    $id_tratamiento = $_GET['id_tratamiento'];
}
        
?>
<?php


include('php/conexion.php');

//traemos los datos del grupo
$sql1 = "SELECT tra.id, nombre_tratamiento, fecha_inicio, fecha_final, observacion, id_diagnostico, id_pacientes, tra.personal, diag.id, nombre_diagnostico,  pa.id as id_pa,  pa.nombre as nompa, pa.telf as telefono, pa.apellidos as apelpa, per.id as id_pa,  per.nombre as nomper, per.apellidos as apelper, especialidad FROM tratamiento tra

INNER JOIN pacientes pa on id_pacientes=pa.id

INNER JOIN personal per on tra.personal=per.id 

INNER JOIN diagnostico diag on id_diagnostico=diag.id 

WHERE tra.id = {$id_tratamiento}";

  $resultados1 = $conexion->query($sql1);
  $datosTratamiento = $resultados1->fetch_array(); 

  $paciente = $datosTratamiento[6];

  $sql= " SELECT * from pacientes JOIN comunidades ON id_comunidad =comunidades.id 

  WHERE pacientes.id = $paciente";

  $resultados = $conexion->query($sql);
  $datosPacientes = $resultados->fetch_array();

  ?>
 
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-factura.css">
 <div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">


<div class="panel-body">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

<!-- CONTENDIO DE LA PAGINA -->
<div id="page_pdf">
  <table id="factura_head textura">
    <tr>
      <td class="logo_factura">

        <div>
        
<img src="http://localhost/yaunde-main/imagenes/logotipo_campo_yaunde.avif" alt="" title="" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="info_empresa">
        <div>
          <span class="h2 textura">CENTRO DE SALUD CAMPO YAUNDE</span>
          <p class="textura">Avenida Hassan II, frente al cuartel Acacio Mane</p>
          <p class="textura">Teléfono: +(240) 222 23-34-33</p>
          
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="info_factura">
        <div >
          <span class="h3 textura" >Inicio y fin del tratamiento</span>
          <p class="textura"><strong>Diagnostico:</strong> <?php echo $datosTratamiento['nombre_diagnostico']; ?></p>
          <p class="textura"><strong>Inicio del tratamiento:</strong> <?php echo $datosTratamiento['fecha_inicio']; ?></p>
          <p class="textura"><strong>Fin del tratameinto:</strong> <?php echo $datosTratamiento['fecha_final']; ?></p>
          
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="factura_cliente">
    <tr>
      <td class="info_cliente">
        <div >
          <span class="h3" class=" textura">INFORMACION DEL PACIENTE</span>
          <table class="datos_cliente textura">
            <tr>
              <td class="td_paciente"><strong>Nombre:</strong> <?php echo $datosTratamiento['nompa']; ?>
              <td class="td_paciente"><strong>Apellidos:</strong> <?php echo $datosTratamiento['apelpa']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="td_paciente"><strong>Telf:</strong> <?php echo $datosTratamiento['telefono']; ?></td>
              <td class="td_paciente"><strong>Dirección:</strong><?php echo $datosPacientes['comunidad']; ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="prescripcion" class=" textura">
    <tr>
      <td class="info_cliente">
        <div >
          
          <table class="datos_cliente " style="border-top: 2px solid #058167" >
            <tr style="border-top: 2px solid #058167; border-bottom: 2px solid #058167;
             color:; padding: 5px; font-size: 12pt;">

          <th class=" textura" width="50px" style=" padding: 8px;">MEDICAMENTOS</th>

          <th class=" textura"  class="textleft" style="text-align: center; padding: 8px;">INSTRUCCIONES</th>
          
        </tr>
            <tr>
              
              <td><label class="textura"> <?php echo $datosTratamiento['nombre_tratamiento']; ?></label> </td>

              <td class="observaciones"> <?php echo $datosTratamiento['observacion']; ?></td>
              
            </tr>
            <tr>
              
              <td colspan="2"></td>
              
            </tr>
            <tr>
             
              <td class="doctor" colspan="2">
                <p class="nota h2 " class=" textura" style="font-weight: bold; ; text-align: center;">DOCTOR/A <?php echo strtoupper($datosTratamiento['nomper'].' '.$datosTratamiento['apelper']);?></p></br>

    <p class="nota "class=" textura" style=" font-weight: bold;"><?php echo strtoupper($datosTratamiento['especialidad']); ?></p>

              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              
              <td colspan="2"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              
              <td colspan="2" class="doctor2">
                <p class="nota " class=" textura">Si usted tiene preguntas sobre esta receta, <br>pongase en contacto con el centro de salud</p>
              </td>

            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

**Finalmente aqui hago el llamado a la libreria de FPDF**

```
<?php
require_once('librerias/fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush(); 

?>
```